# Python Scrapy and Selenium printing so much data that I don't expect at all

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I'm working on a project which involves scraping several websites in one run. Since I'm not able to parse some of them with bare scrapy, I have to use selenium. [I've already applied `scrapy-selenium` but the problem is with one of the urls that has my desired element inside shadow roots so using selenium find_element method is obligatory.]

My problem is, although I get my result but there's so much printing in the terminal. see image below:
[image]

Any instructions?

Thanks

`Update`

here's the code:

```
# in start_requests()
yield SeleniumRequest(url="https://eu.usatoday.com/",
                      callback=self.parse_usatoday,)

# in parse_usatoday()
d = response.request.meta['driver']
cust = []
sections = d.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='post-content']//promo-story-bucket-short")
for s in sections:
    shadow_root_main = s.shadow_root
    sr2 = shadow_root_main.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "lit-story-thumb-large").shadow_root
    cust.append(sr2.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a"))
    for lit in shadow_root_main.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "lit-story-card"):
        sr2 = lit.shadow_root
        cust.append(sr2.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a"))
al = []
at = []
for item in cust:
    href = item.get_attribute('href')
    al.append(href)
    at.append(item.text)
```

I know I shouldn't use selenium inside scrapy, but with this I get my result. The only problem is with those so much printing.

Comment: how can you print anything in the terminal with literally 0 lines of code? Does this printing magically come from the air?

Comment: I'll update my question now. thanks for mentioning it. totally forgot it.

Comment: mmm I don't see any print statement. Maybe selenium is internally printing all this internally. You will have to check in the Selenium API

Comment: so you think it's unrelated to using selenium inside scrapy? because in other ways I've tried scraping the same url, there wasn't this problem. so thought maybe I need to apply some sorta configuration.

Comment: At a guess you're attempting to find anchors.  If that is the case, I'd look at trying `cust.append(sr2.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "a"))` instead of `By.CSS_SELECTOR`. Your current selector is returning all elements with the letter a, instead of just anchors/URLs.

Comment: you should add the line that prints to terminal... it's hard to say what's happening without seeing that.  You've got what may be javascript from the driver printing...  that might just be webelement references printing as text.